# Global configuration in go.cd

Tags: go-cd, thoughtworks-go

Is there any way to define some kind of global parameter in go.cd? I want to define a few parameters that are common for all pipelines (e.g. url of the server containing all my repositories).

AFAIK, there are two possibilities to parametrize build, but none is appropriate for global configuration:

- parameters are defined for single pipeline/template
- environment variables are only usable inside tasks

Answer (score 0):

[**Not** a best solution]

For a quick hack, you can try defining the environment variable(s) on the machines(which have the Go agent installed) may work?

If you are using Linux machines export the variable(s) inside the bash environment and use them inside the tasks?

However, you may need to manage these environment variables on the go agent machines via some other tool.

Comment: Sorry for late reply! Unfortunately environment variables are not usable in my case. As I wrote, they are only usable after the task started. I can't use them directly in config.xml.
My solution (actually, not solution, but act of surrender) was to hardcode all paramaters.